# Does "outward normal" to a surface from the a given point of observation determine the normals?

Tags: definition, conventions

It is often mentioned in subjects having 3-d vector calculus to consider an orientable surface and an observation point, and consider the normal vectors to the surface "outward" from the observation point.

But this is highly ambiguous! Consider the following situation. The point $O$ induces *both* possible ways to have normals. In such cases, do we take that set of normals that $O$ induces via the point on the surface nearest to $O$, so that we'll take the red set of normals?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An orientable surface (in this context assumed to be closed) encloses a volume (although I can't put my finger on the rigorous topological theorem) so the observer is either inside or outside.

Comment: I always thought that xy plane was orientable. Is it not?

Comment: @Atom That's not closed, but it still divides space into two parts.